# How can I run vector field plotting applet math.la.asu.edu using Java(TM) Platform?

Tags: browser-addons

The website in question can be found [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/), and allows plotting vector fields - it is a great resource with all sorts of bells and whistles.

I can access it as I write these lines on a different computer, where I have installed the browser Pale Moon just to be able to run this website - I remember a couple of years ago spending a ton of time researching, and finally getting it up and running on Pale Moon, where I have Java(TM) Platform SE 8 U161 as a plugin, as well as Java Deployment Toolkit 8.0.1610.12.

I don't remember how I got those plugins, and I think that the version of Pale Moon I just downloaded is not compatible with Java.

I don't care about running the applet in Pale Moon, Chrome, Opera, Mozilla or IE, but how can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, on Windows 10:

1. Install "CheerpJ Applet Runner" plugin:
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein
2. Go to:
   https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/
3. Click on CheerpJ icon. Press: "Run Applets"
4. Wait 3 minutes, while CheerpJ dynamically converts the Applet to Javascript.
5. Use converted Applet/Javascript, with excellent performance.

N.B. you are not running the original Applet, so it may or may not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10:

1. Install [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/win10.jsp).
2. From the Start search box in the lower-left hand corner type Internet Explorer
3. Start Internet Explorer 11 (not Edge), and allow Java in any pop-up questions.
4. Type in the search box within IE11 [https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Ekawski/vfa2/)
5. Click on Allow in any pop-up windows asking whether the site is trusted.
6. Click OK on the pop-up message "Application Blocked by Java Security."
7. Go to Internet Options => Security => Trusted Sites, and add https://math.la.asu.edu
8. Go back to the Start search box and type Java => Configure Java
9. Under the Security tab => Edit Site List => Add => [https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Ekawski/vfa2/)
10. Re-start IE11, and click on Run when asked "Do you want to run this application?"

AND 11! All the above may apply (for instance, placing the website URL in the Java control panel exception list is necessary), BUT it is not enough! I have managed to run the applet by downloading and using the [Pale Moon browser.](https://www.palemoon.org/)

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816839/how-do-i-enable-java-in-microsoft-edge-web-browser) (more general).